# Cross platform installation conventions & best practices

Tags: linux, windows, macos, plugins

I manage an open source project that we currently distribute as a zipped bundle of files.  We provide a bundle for Windows and Mac -- we currently expect Linux users to compile it themselves.

This program comes with a bunch of auxiliary files that the user will need to access.  These include example files and example/default scripts (like plugins) that the user will need to be able to easily find (preferably not searching through a maze of /usr/local/foo/examples/scripts).

The user will also have their own files (that they may want to store in random locations), but they will also have their own collection of scripts (that they probably want centralized so they are always available).

I would like to support installation in multi-user environments where the user does not have permissions to mess with the program installation.  The program will include an API (shared library and header) and a Python wrapper for that too.  It would be nice to make those available automatically.

We build the project with CMake - and currently use CPack to bundle the zip files.  CPack has much more capability than we are currently using.  This is not a mechanical question of how to build the package/installation files, but a convention question of where to put all the stuff?

We would like to have an Application on MacOS, an installer for Windows, and packages for Linux.  Mac Apps package icons, fonts, images, etc. nicely, but they don't seem to support user-visible files very well.

I would love for there to be a cross-platform standard way of handling this situation, but I have trouble finding decent examples on individual platforms.

Is there anything better for us to do than just a zip of files?

Answer (score 0):

Providing archive of those extra files is probably one of the best solutions. You may encourage users to download them on first start of program - let users decide where they want them themselves.